# How to create a list of buttons from a list?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a scrollable list and an array of objects (about 300 to 400). The objects have two properties, a string name and a string prefab path.

I need to add a button for each object, how would I go about creating these buttons using scripting?

Comment: I feel I should reconfirm the issue I raise in my answer; You do not just create a `Button` in Unity, you create a `GameObject` with UI components (you ask for a `Button`, but seem to describe also having a `Text`). You might be able to use the old deprecated `GUI.Button`, though earlier versions of Unity have had problems due to support for the newer `UI.Button`. All that aside, **your creating 300 to 400 buttons**. I have never worked with so many UI elements at once, but I think your going to have some memory problems.

Comment: I've sorted it now, I'm implementing a more elaborate menu system to avoid having more than 50 buttons at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a button in Unity is quite simple, via scripting. Once you understand how create *a single* button, it should not be complicated to create a *list* of buttons. Let's take a look at [the Unity manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/).

#### Step One: Make a Prefab

> In order to be able to easily instantiate UI elements dynamically, the first step is to create a prefab for the type of UI element that you want to be able to instantiate. Set up the UI element the way you want it to look in the Scene, and then drag the element into the Project View to make it into a prefab.
>   <sub>**- [Unity Manual: Creating UI elements from scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)**</sub>

Simple enough, really. Make a prototype for your button. Set it up to look exactly how you want it to, and ensure it has all the components you intend to use. Save it as a prefab, so we can reference it via code. Ultimately, you have to do this because there are no public constructors for UI elements. The manual further explains the logic behind this:

> You might wonder why we don’t have a API methods to create the various types of controls, including visuals and everything. The reason is that there are an infinite number of way e.g. a button could be setup. Does it use an image, text, or both? Maybe even multiple images? What is the text font, color, font size, and alignment? What sprite or sprites should the image use?
>   <sub>**- [Unity Manual: Creating UI elements from scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)**</sub>

### Step Two: Instantiate an instance of your prefab

> Prefabs of UI elements are instantiated as normal using the `Instantiate` method. When setting the parent of the instantiated UI element, it’s recommended to do it using the `Transform.SetParent` method with the `worldPositionStays` parameter set to `false`.
>   <sub>**- [Unity Manual: Creating UI elements from scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)**</sub>

Following the simple route, we are using some basic Unity methods to instantiate and set up the button. First and foremost, we are using `UI.Button`, so ensure you include `using UnityEngine.UI` or otherwise refer to the button object as `UI.Button`. Note that we reference the actual button object as a `GameObject`, as you will need to include *other* components to provide realistic functionality. You will also need to have a reference to *at least* the game object that holds your canvas component (if not, a child of that object), as you will need to parent the button to the canvas when you instantiate it.

In the below example, I have provided both the prefab and the canvas reference as `public` variables, so I can simply drag and drop them in through the Unity editor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MinorTestMono : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject buttonPrefab;
    public GameObject canvasParent;

    void InstantiatePrefab()
    {
        GameObject sample = Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
        sample.transform.SetParent(canvasParent.transform, false);
    }
}
```

### Further customisation

You would likely want to add some customisation to each button. How you do so is up to you, especially given that you have not told us *how* the button should look, at all. You should consider reading [the aforementioned manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html), as it elaborates on how to do so, and makes further suggestions.

Assuming you wish to include a string display on the button, you will need to include a `UI.Text` component on your original button prefab. From there, it is just a matter of directly changing the text component. You can do this inline, with something like `sample.GetComponent<Text>().text = "this is a button";`.

### Regarding lists

Now you know how to create a button, doing so as an array should be childs-play. If it is not, you should focus on familiarising yourself with how arrays work, before dealing with the creation of a 400+ array of game objects.

**I *will* give some pointers:**

- I have never personally worked with such a large number of UI elements, and will forewarn that I do not think it will run very well, in the implementation you describe. If you only wish to display a certain number of buttons at once, consider creating a more complicated system, where buttons that disappear off screen are "recycled" for use as the new buttons that appear on screen. This way, your keeping record of the exact amount of buttons you need to be *visible*, and memory usage will be a lot lighter. *Do not just ask a new question on 'how do I do that' without actually researching it for yourself, as you will likely need to put a lot more effort into this approach.*
- Ensure your `GameObject` array runs *parallel* to your other array; that is, `button[1]` should be using `object[1]` for its path and name, `button[2] should be using`object[2](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)`, and so on.
- Keep your game objects *simple*. If you do not use a particular component, do not keep it. Remember, you are potentially creating 400 iterations of this game object.

Answer (score 0):

I have another (I think much better) answer. When I created a quest system for a simple RPG, I also needed a List or array in buttons. I found out, that a 'List' and 'foreach' is a much easier way to do this so here is my code:

```
public List<Quest> activeQuests = new List<Quest> ();

public GameObject ButtonParent;

public GameObject ButtonCanvas;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) {
        if (ButtonCanvas.activeInHierarchy) {

            ButtonCanvas.SetActive(false);

        } else {
            ButtonCanvas.SetActive (true);

            foreach (Quest currentQuest in activeQuests) {
                GameObject currentButton = Instantiate (ButtonPrefab, ButtonCanvas.transform, false);
                //use currentQuest for your GameObject like Array[i] in for
            }
        }
    }
}
```